# Angular 15: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

I'm on learning angular and I wrote a angular project has file structure:
[File structure of angular project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz7mp.png)

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './theme/Layout/default-layout/default-layout.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
        loadChildren: () => import('./routers/routers.module').then((x) => x.RoutersModule),
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

theme.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BannerComponent } from './Layout/banner/banner.component';
import { DataTableComponent } from './Layout/data-table/data-table.component';
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './Layout/default-layout/default-layout.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './Layout/footer/footer.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [BannerComponent, DataTableComponent, DefaultLayoutComponent, FooterComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ThemeModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ThemeModule } from './theme/theme.module';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule, ThemeModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I want to use `<router-outlet>` in the default-layout.

default-layout.component.html:

```
<app-banner></app-banner>
<p>default-layout works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The problem is:

> 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

**edit**:
I resolve problem by import `RouterModule` in `ThemeModule` , `imports: [RouterModule]` follow @NavoneelTalukdar's advice in the comment

Comment: Hi @NavoneelTalukdar, I added `exports: [DataTableComponent, DefaultLayoutComponent, FooterComponent]` to theme.module.ts but it is not resolve <router-oulet> issue

Comment: Import `RouterModule` in your `ThemeModule` and export custom compoenents from `ThemeModule`

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar, I have another issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434626/angular-provide-component-in-root) can you give me advice.