# Angular: provide component in root

Tags: angular

I'm on learning angular and I wrote a angular project has file structure:

File structure of angular project

[image: 1]

data-table.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, PipeTransform, Pipe, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss'],
})
export class DataTableComponent {
    @Input() dataTableConfig: any;
    @Input() dataContent: any;
}
```

theme.module.ts:

```
import { TableComponent } from './Layout/table/table.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TableComponent,
    ],
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
    providers: [],
})
export class ThemeModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ThemeModule } from './theme/theme.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule, ThemeModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

routers.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RoutersRoutingModule } from './routers-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [CommonModule, RoutersRoutingModule],
})
export class RoutersModule {}
```

category.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CategoryRoutingModule } from './category-routing.module';
import { TestCategoryComponent } from './test-category/test-category.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestCategoryComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, CategoryRoutingModule],
})
export class CategoryModule {}
```

test-category.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-category',
  templateUrl: './test-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-category.component.scss']
})
export class TestCategoryComponent {
  dataTableConfig = [//...some data];
  dataContent = [//...some data];
}
```

How can I use `<app-data-table [dataTableConfig]='dataTableConfig' [dataContent]='dataContent'>` in `test-category.component.html` or everywhere I want

When I try it the error is:

> 'app-data-table' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-data-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-data-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestCategoryComponent` uses the module it is declared in, `CategoryModule`, to look up other components.

It can either use declared components from the declarations array
OR
Any exported components from modules your `CategoryModule` imports.

I recommend the SCAM (single component angular module) approach,

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DataTableComponent],
    exports: [DataTableComponent]
})
export class DataTableModule {}
```

You then import `DataTableModule` into `CategoryModule`. Since the imported module exports `DataTableComponent` it is available in this context.

From angular 15, you can make components standalone and import them like a module (they keep their own context and import NgModules or other standalone components as they need via the imports array within the Component decorator).

```
@Component({
    standalone: true, // <----------------------
    // imports: [NgIf, JsonPipe], // example if `DataTableComponent` uses ngIf and a json pipe
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss'],
})
export class DataTableComponent {
    @Input() dataTableConfig: any;
    @Input() dataContent: any;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. With your advice I resolved my problem. Have a great day!